# Event is null after restarting app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

current I have an event in my App.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static event EventHandler SettingsSaved;

        private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SettingsSaved != null)
            {
                SettingsSaved(this, null);
            }
     }
```

and in my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {        
        InitializeComponent();

        App.SettingsSaved += App_SettingsSaved;

    }

    void App_SettingsSaved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //do something here
    }
```

SettingsSaved works fine when the app is launched for the first time, but when the app is launched the second time, SettingsSaved becomes null. Is there a way to make sure SettingsSaved works the same as it does when the app is launched the first time?

I'm a novice coder and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if wp8 is anything like metro apps there's probably a separate part of the lifecycle with different event handlers for resuming. Generally it seems apps aren't killed, but rather suspended and then resumed. Might be a place to start looking...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it in the public MainPage(), maybe try putting it in an App.Initialize event to ensure it absolutely happens on start-up.

Comment: Hi @isme, I'm not quite sure if I understand you, but I can't subscribe to the event from App.Initialize because I need to access objects from MainPage.xaml in my App_SettingsSaved method. Sorry again if I didn't understand you correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant put the App.SettingsSaved+=SettingsSaved inside of a MainPage.Initialize event, that way you can be sure it does become assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem. I believe I have to subscribe to the event first before I can fire the event, in my code above, I wasn't able to subscribe to it first because App.xaml.cs is executed first before I can subscribe to it in my Mainpage.xaml.cs.

This works for me the first time I started my app because I had some additional code which awaited something.

My solution is more of a hack where I awaited a delayed task like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static event EventHandler SettingsSaved;

    private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        //this await will cause the thread to jump to MainPage to subscribe to SettingsSaved event.
        await Task.Delay(500);

        if (SettingsSaved != null)
        {
            SettingsSaved(this, null);
        }
 }
```

Of course I would appreciate it very much if someone could come up with a more elegant solution where the MainPage can be initialized first before continuing with the code in App.xaml.cs